# Can somebody explain to me, how the Hyperparameters in this expamle work? I only uderstood the meaning for gamma

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, hyperparameter-tuning, hyperparameter

I am quite new to this topic, but I want to understand how Reinforcement Learning (RL) works in this example (https://gymnasium.farama.org/tutorials/training_agents/reinforce_invpend_gym_v26/). I have a fundamental understanding of the entire process, but I don't quite grasp how the hyperparameters work in this context and how I can tune them. I've read a lot about RL and understand its structure. I also grasp how the gamma parameter works, but I haven't found much information about the other two hyperparameters. If somebody could help me, that would be great! Thank you, everybody.

Comment: Can you please describe what the "two hyperparameters" are?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.